# import {FormControl,FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

FormsModule has imported on app.module.ts but the problem persists.

Can't bind to 'ngModule' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

```
 ("item</h1>
      <form (submit)="addItem()" #form="ngForm">
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is exactly the issue? And please share the code. Thanks!

Comment: Appear as an error message when I run the project, I already imported the FormsModule in the app.module.ts but the error persists.
This is the message: Can't bind to 'ngModule' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("item

Comment: Please post what you did so that we can help you.

Comment: Which components are you working on? Where do you want to put your form?

Comment: I'm working on cadastroitens component, my complete project stay here if you want see https://github.com/dizwes/angular6

Comment: You should be using `[(ngModel)]` instead of  `[(ngModule)]`

Comment: Ohhh god, forgive bro and thak you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your app.module.ts add the following import:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule  } from "@angular/forms";
```

and add them to the imports section:

```
imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
],
```

**Edit:**

There are two possible reasons:

Missing `FormsModule`, hence Add this to your Module,

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        FormsModule      
    ]
```

Since you don't use the reactive forms you can remove `ReactiveFormsModule` from the imports.

Check the syntax/spelling of `[(ngModel)]` in the input tag.

Comment: Still did not work :(

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ROUTES } from './routes';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: did you add the following imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
],

Comment: Yeah.
imports: [ FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),],

Comment: please post the html code ans also the component ts

Comment: That's my form template:
<form (submit)="addItem()">
        <input type="text"  name="title" [(ngModule)]="title" placeholder="Digite aqui">
        <input type="text"  name="description" [(ngModule)]="description" placeholder="Digite aqui">
        <button type="submit" class="addBtn" value="Add Item" >
          Adicionar
        </button>
      </form>

Comment: and this is my component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {  Item } from './cadastro.model';
import { CadastroService } from './cadastro.service';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-cadastroitens',
  templateUrl: './cadastroitens.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cadastroitens.component.scss']
})
export class CadastroitensComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( 
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }

}

Comment: actually since you don't want to use reactive forms it's better to delete ReactiveFormsModule  from the imports. FormsModule import should fix your isuue !

Comment: i snot working, my complete project stay here if you want see: https://github.com/dizwes/angular6

Comment: change [(ngModule)] to [(ngModel)].

Comment: Ohhh god, forgive bro and thak you so much!

Comment: You're so welcome. Glad i helped.